# Possible to do with django forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form where an administrators enters a list of comma-separated email addresses, and the form does validation on each email address before adding it to the db. I was able to do this just fine with using my own (non-django) form. I tried to migrate this over to using modelforms, but ran into a few problems. Here is the code I currently have --

```
# model
class EmailList(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network)

class EmailListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailList

    def clean_email(self):
      if self.cleaned_data['email']:
          valid_emails = []
          for x in self.cleaned_data['email'].split(','):
              x = x.strip().lower()
              valid_emails.append(x)
          return valid_emails

# in views
def email(request):
    if request.POST.get('email'):
        for email in form.cleaned_data.get('email'):  ### ??
            if form.is_valid():                       ### ??
                EmailList.objects.create(email = email, network=Network.objects.get(id=request.POST['network']))
        return redirect('.')
```

I am having trouble because I can't call on the `cleaned_data()` until the form is validated, but the form will not validate as a whole (only its iterations will). Is it possible to construct this function using django's forms? If so, how would I accomplish this task? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I wouldn't use a `ModelForm` because they are for the case that you want to represent one Model instance by one Form. Here you want to produce multiple instances with one form. So just write a common form with a custom field (there is acutally an example just for this in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning)) and maybe a custom save method:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import validate_email

class MultiEmailField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        "Normalize data to a list of strings."

        # Return an empty list if no input was given.
        if not value:
            return []
        return value.split(',')

    def validate(self, value):
        "Check if value consists only of valid emails."

        # Use the parent's handling of required fields, etc.
        super(MultiEmailField, self).validate(value)

        for email in value:
            validate_email(email)


class EmailListForm(forms.Form):
    emails = forms.MulitEmailField()
    network = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Network.objects.all())

    # save the emails to the db
    def save(self):
        for email in self.cleaned_data.get('emails'):
            EmailList.objects.create(email = email,
                                     network=self.network)

# in views
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(...somewhere...)
    else:
        form = EmailListForm()

    return render(request, 'some/template.html', { 'form': form }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful. Does `class MultiEmailField` go in forms.py or in the model?

Comment: You're very welcome :) It goes actually in fields.py in the same directory as forms.py und models.py